# Enviar email usando ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Gostaria de saber como enviar um email usando o ASP.NET. A ideia será clicar num button chamado enviar e envia um mail de suportcegos@sapo.pt (pessoal) para nsoares@cegoc.pt (empresarial).
Obrigado.

Comment: http://codigosimples.net/2016/03/29/envio-de-emails-simples-com-gmail/

Comment: Sua pergunta no Google achará varias respostas. Aqui http://www.mundoasp.net/enviar-email-com-asp-dot-net/ tem bem detalhado o que você precisa. Na verdade precisará usar somente alguns das propriedades citadas.

Comment: Dá erro de "Unable to connect to the server". Algumas ideias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo com asp.net mvc4 e javascript:

**MVC:**

```
public ActionResult SendEmail()
{
    var fromAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
    var toAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
    const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
    const string subject = "Subject";
    const string body = "Body";

    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar">Enviar</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#enviar").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SendEmail", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Um email foi enviado com sucesso');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Dá erro de "Unable to connect to the server". Algumas ideias?

Comment: @NelsonSoares, você tem que configurar o seu Cliente para envio de emails pelo `smtp.sapo.pt`, o seguinte endereço pode lhe ser util: [Configuração POP/ IMAP/ SMTP](http://ajuda.sapo.pt/pt-pt/mail/faq/cat/acesso-por-programas-de-email)... posivelmente `Host = "smtp.sapo.pt", Port = 587, EnableSsl = true` ou `Host = "smtp.sapo.pt", Port = 25, EnableSsl = false`... lembrando que deve usar o seu email e passwords verdadeiros.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo de uma forma diferente, mas com os mesmos métodos da resposta do @Spectron, ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult EnviarEmail(){

 using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {

                        var message = new MailMessage();
                        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("suportcegos@sapo.pt"));
                        message.From = new MailAddress("nsoares@cegoc.pt ");
                        message.Subject = "Assunto";
                        message.Body = "Seu Texto Aqui";
                        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        var credential = new NetworkCredential
                        {
                            UserName = "suportcegos@sapo.pt", 
                            Password = "Senha do E-mail aqui"
                        };
                        smtp.Credentials = credential;
                        smtp.Host = "HOST aqui (ex: smtp.google.com)";
                        smtp.Port = 587; //(Porta aqui)
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true; //(SSL Enable)
                        smtp.Send(message);//Enviar mensagem
                    }
                }
    return View();
}
```

Porém, aconselho você utilizar o [Postal.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Postal.Mvc5) para realizar o envio. [Neste Link](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/tree/master/src/Samples/WebSample) possui um exemplo do autor do projeto de como implementar, basta realizar o download do projeto.